# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in didReceiveRemoteNotification but after webView is loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, webview, push-notification

I am facing a problem in iOS push notification in a Cordova hybrid app, need guidance/help in identifying whether I am doing it the right way?
Here is the flow ->

1. User recieved push notification while app is in background -> Tap on the notification from the notification center -> App is opened (invoked) -> Get the custom payload values -> perform a JS Callback using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` -> The JS function will do the necessary actions the app has to do.

Here is my code where I am doing it

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] receivedPush:userInfo]; //Using Pushbots notification platform

    NSString* Value1 = [userInfo objectForKey:@"val1"];
    NSString* Value2 = [userInfo objectForKey:@"val2"];

    NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testfromdelegate('%@','%@')", Value1, Value2];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsCallBack);
    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
}
```

Everything works till my `NSLog(@"%@", jsCallBack);`, and it fails at the jsCallBack. I understood that by the time my jsCallBack is being called, the webView is not yet ready, as the app is invoked from background.

1. What do I do to make this work? How to check whether my webView is ready, and then perform my jsCallBack?
2. How do I do this when the app is not running at all? For e.g., a user received a Whatsapp message and the app is not in background/foreground. But when the user taps on the message from the notification center, the whatsapp app opens with the user chat screen.

**PS:** All this code perfectly works when the app is in foreground. That means, the webView is already there and so jsCallBack has no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is in open or in background, then you can execute the javascript directly:

```
//This will be called if the app was open, in the foreground (active) or in the background and you reopen it from a push message
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] receivedPush:userInfo]; //Using Pushbots notification platform

    NSString* Value1 = [userInfo objectForKey:@"val1"];
            NSString* Value2 = [userInfo objectForKey:@"val2"];
            NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testfromdelegate('%@','%@')", Value1, Value2];
            NSLog(@"%@", jsCallBack);
    // If the app is in the foreground just execute the javascript        
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {
        [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jsCallBack];
    } else {
         // If the app was in background, then force to execute the js code on the main thread
        [self.viewController.webView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject:jsCallBack waitUntilDone:NO]
    }

}
```

If the app was completelly closed, then you can add an observer that will listen for the CDVPageDidLoadNotification (cordova finish loading), so you store the userInfo in a new variable `myUserInfo` and wait until the page is loaded to use it:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    //Don't remove the existing code, just paste this before the return YES
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(cordovaDidLoad) name:CDVPageDidLoadNotification object:self.viewController.webView];
    //This will be called if the app was closed completelly and you open it from a push
    if (launchOptions) { //launchOptions is not nil
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        self.myUserInfo = userInfo;
    }

    return YES;

}
```

Then, when cordova is loaded this method will be called:

```
- (void)cordovaDidLoad {
    //Check that myUserInfo isn't null, that will mean that the apps was completelly closed and it was opened from the push notification
    if (self.myUserInfo) {
        NSString* Value1 = [self.myUserInfo objectForKey:@"val1"];
        NSString* Value2 = [self.myUserInfo objectForKey:@"val2"];
        NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testfromdelegate('%@','%@')", Value1, Value2];
        NSLog(@"%@", jsCallBack);
        [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jsCallBack];
    }

}
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for! thanks jcesarmobile!! I needed a listener that waits until the webview is loaded and then perform jscallback.
But I get an error "Property 'myUserInfo' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'

Comment: yeah, you have to create the property myUserInfo (in your appDelegate.h put @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary * myUserInfo;

Comment: got it! So, I had initialized my object in .h
Now I get an error after I received my notification and tapped on it. This I saw at the breakpoint on the line - [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(cordovaDidLoad) name:CDVPageDidLoadNotification object:self.viewController.webView];


*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setMyUserInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1555fc20'
***

Comment: should that be "performSelector:@selector(cordovaDidLoad)" instead of "selector:@selector(cordovaDidLoad)". Am just almost there! If this works, it will be a great help :-)

Comment: No, the code is right, you cant use performSelector there, addObserver just have toe selector method. I've just tested the code and works, which xcode version are you using? BTW, I've added some modifications you should see

Comment: the XCODE version am using is 6.3.2. Would that be a problem?

Comment: no, the problem might be with old versions that don't auto synthesize properties, so, if you use xcode 6.3.2 is strange that you get the  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setMyUserInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1555fc20' ***

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83172/discussion-between-lohith-krishna-and-jcesarmobile).

Comment: The error's gone now. I am receiving the notification but it never reaches the cordovaDidLoad function. It terminates at the [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter].... line :'(

but here is some good things happening 
_myUserInfo __NSCFDictionary * 3 key/value pairs 0x15634920
CDVPageDidLoadNotification __NSCFConstantString * @"CDVPageDidLoadNotification" 0x00063b88